# How to add text in a link tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

How to change tikzset the text is automatically added to the link

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{mylink/.style={dashed,->}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0){a};

\node[circle,draw] (b) at (5,2){b};

\draw[mylink](a) -- node{aaa}(b) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What text are you talking about?  If you to add a text node along an arrow you can just add a node after `(b)` and add the `pos=0.5` key.

Comment: Do you want to change the link *text* (the `aaa` in your example) or the link *style* (for example, the positioning of the label above or below the line)?

Comment: I want to automatically add the text "aaa"  with the style

Comment: `\tikzset{mylink/.style={dashed,->, every to/.append style={to path=-- node {aaa} (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}}` and then you can use `\draw [myling] (a) to (b);`

Comment: ok, but can be replaced (a) to (b)  by  (a) -- (b).

Answer (score 2):

You have about three ways to get automatically nodes with styles.

The easiest one is to use a `to` path operator and simply change the used `to path` to

```
-- node {#1} (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
```

(This will of course only work with `--` paths.)

If you insist on using `--` in your path, you can use the `decorations.markings` library and automatically mark these paths with a node:

```
mark=at position .5 with {\node {#1};}
```

This will also work with non-straight (`--`/`line to`) paths.

The third option is only available with the current CVS version of PGF and uses the so-called edge nodes. Similar to solution 1, I change the `every edge` style to onclude this `edge node`. (We could also have used `every to` and `to` in the path.)
The advantage here is that we still can change the path to for example a `curve to`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    mylink/.style={
        dashed,
        ->,
    },
    aaa/.style={
        every to/.append style={
            to path=-- node {#1} (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
        }
    },
    aaa/.default=aaa,
    bbb/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position .5 with {\node {#1};}
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    bbb/.default=bbb,
    ccc/.style={
        every edge/.append style={edge node=node {#1}}
    },
    ccc/.default=ccc
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[circle,draw] (b) at (5,2) {b};
\draw[mylink, aaa] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[circle,draw] (b) at (5,2) {b};
\draw[mylink, bbb] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[circle,draw] (b) at (5,2) {b};
\draw[mylink, ccc, curve to] (a) edge (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]