# How to allow labels' anchors in TikZ to be affected by rotations without rotating the text itself?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rotating, scaling

I usually write macros when I need to draw many times a kind of figure. In the final document, I call the macro and then I always apply two transformations : a scale transformation to fit in the space I've left, and a rotation so that my students are not facing exactly the same situation. Unfortunately, labels won't be well positioned after a rotation.

Here is what I get using the anchor `below left` and `midway,below` after different rotations.

[image: labels not well-positioned after different rotations]

Here is what I would like to have.

[image: labels well-positioned even after different rotations]

Here is what I would like to avoid if I'm scaling the draw.

[image: what I don't want to see after scaling]

Here is the code I'm using to try to solve my problem:

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myDraw}[2]{% \myDraw{rotation angle}{scale factor}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
\centering \footnotesize $\theta=#1^{\circ}$, $k=#2$ \medskip\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#1,scale=#2]
    \draw (0,1) -- (0,0) node[below left] {$O$} -- (1,0) node[midway,below] {$1$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\myDraw{0}{0.5}
\myDraw{45}{0.7}
\myDraw{90}{1}
\myDraw{135}{1.3}
\myDraw{180}{1.5}
\end{document}
```

I thought of manually positioning my label, but then the distance between the label and the point would be affected by a scale transformation and I lose the ability of using convenient keywords like `midway` and `pos=`.

I could also use the key `transform shape` as a `node` option, but then the text would be rotated and scaled.

If you think my question doesn't reflect my issue, you are very welcome to edit it (I had a hard time to figure out how to explain my problem).

Comment: If you don’t use `scale` but `x=2cm, y=2cm` you can use the `transform shape` option on the `O` node. — What would be a “pleasant position”?

Comment: Indeed, the text is not scaled anymore but it'is still rotated.

I mean by "peasant position" that relative position of the label evolves according to the rotation of the whole figure.

Comment: is it only rotation that you wish to apply as a transform?

Comment: Actually I want to apply both rotation and scale, so my question is still confusing. I'm will edit my question, I must say it doesn't make much sense written like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Anchor` key defines two coordinate with the current transformation matrix active (scaling, rotating, whatever) and from that calculates the angle between these coordinates in the canvas for an un-transformed node.

The code for the `Anchor` style was inspired by [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119884/16595) (which could be simplified) to [Small text near arrow tips](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118843/16595).

The `Anchor` style probably works best with the `circle` or the `ellipse` shape.
The `rectangle` shape is very nonuniform.

Of course, you can define styles like `Below Left/.style={Anchor=45}` if you want to use directions for the current transformation matrix.

---

The code uses `\pgfcoordinate` which is quick version of `\pgfnode` for a `coordinate`.
Instead of the `\pgfcoordinate`s we could have written

```
\path  (0,0) coordinate (qrr@origin)
      (#1:1) coordinate (qrr@direct);
```

The matrix transformation is then reset (so that we are back in coordinate system that has the same orientation as our canvas in which we place the un-transformed node) with `\pgftransformreset`.

The macro `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` is not documented in the PGF manual. It is defined in `pgfmathcalc.code.tex` after a block that warns

```
% *** The following commands DO NOT WORK without the rest of PGF ***
%
% (a dumping ground for stuff that doesn't really belong anywhere else)
```

The instruction for `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` read

```
% \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
%
% Define \pgfmathresult as the angle between points #1 and #2
% Should get the quadrants right as well.
```

In the linked answer of mine I did practically the same as that macro but in a manual manner (and maybe not as precise).

The TeX group is necessary so that `\pgftransformreset` doesn’t affect the actual placement of the node. The `\pgfmath@smuggleone` (or its `@`-less version `\pgfmathsmuggle`) is then used to “smuggle” `\pgfmathresult` out of the group. The `\pgfmath@smuggleone` macro is used very often in PGF math. It’s definition in `pgfmathutil.code.tex` is

```
% \pgfmath@smuggleone
%
% Smuggle a macro outside a group.
%
% Changed by TT: Speedup by insisting, that smuggleone is directly
% followed by \endgroup
%
\def\pgfmath@smuggleone#1\endgroup{%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}}  

\let\pgfmathsmuggle=\pgfmath@smuggleone
```

The advance over `\global`ing it is that it only affects one group and not all.

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  Anchor/.code=%
    \begingroup
      \pgfcoordinate{qrr@origin}{\pgfpointorigin}%
      \pgfcoordinate{qrr@direct}{\pgfpointpolarxy{#1}{1}}%
      \pgftransformreset
      \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{qrr@origin}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{qrr@direct}{center}}%
      \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
    \endgroup
    \tikzset{anchor/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}%
}
\newcommand{\myDraw}[2]{% \myDraw{rotation angle}{scale factor}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
\centering \footnotesize $\theta=#1^{\circ}$, $k=#2$ \medskip\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#1,scale=#2]
    \draw (0,1) -- (0,0) node[Anchor=45] {$O$} -- (1,0) node[midway,Anchor=90] {$1$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\myDraw{0}{0.5}
\myDraw{45}{0.7}
\myDraw{90}{1}
\myDraw{135}{1.3}
\myDraw{180}{1.5}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is really a great answer, exactly what I was looking for... Thank you! I must admit I don't understand most of it though!

Comment: Let say that I want my anchor angle to be 45° and that the current transformation is a rotation of 100°. Then, before `\pgftransformreset`, the point `qrr@direct` polar angle is 145° since the current transformation matrix is applied. After `\pgftransformreset`, the transformation matrix is reset in the scope so `\pgfpointanchor` can't apply the inverse transformation matrix. Hence, the angle computed stays 145°. This value is then passed on to the anchor/.expanded handler. Am I right? I'm not used to pgf but I really want to understand what's going on here.

Comment: @remjg That’s the gist of it, yes. One could probably also calculate the rotation from the entries of transformation matrix but this looks much easier (and basically does it).

Comment: Also, I would like to ask you about the meaning of `\pgfinterruptboundingbox` and `\endpgfinterruptboundingbox`. I've removed them without seeing any differences. As far as I've understood, the bounding box is the rectangle that is uses to clip the draw for the rendering. Using the previous commands, you want that the points `qrr@direct` and `qrr@origin` (used to compute the anchor angle) not to be considered as part of the draw?

Comment: @remjg Yes, in your case both points already lie in the current bounding box but this may not be true for every diagram. Change `\pgfpointpolarxy{#1}{1}` to `\pgfpointpolarxy{#1}{10}` and there should be a notable difference.

Comment: I've already tried something similar without seeing a different result, that why I thought I had misunderstood something. It doesn't matter anyway, all I wanted was to know if my understanding of these commands was correct.

Comment: I still have one question if you don't mind. I can't find anything written about the commands `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` and `\pgfmath@smuggleone` in the _TikZ and PGF manual 2.1_. Where did you find those?

Comment: @remjg You are correct, they do not matter here as I have used the shortcut `\pgfcoordinate` (which neither creates a path nor updates the bounding box) instead of `\pgfnode` as in my other answer. The code be simplified. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your explanations, I've learned a lot today with your answers!

Comment: Salut, j'ai complété ma réponse/ I completed my answer

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if this will satisfy you, the question is not very precise.
I added the library `calc` to determine the position of the text.
The texts "O" is then positioned relative to the origin, same for "I".

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\myDraw}[2]{% \myDraw{rotation angle}{scale factor}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
\centering \footnotesize $\theta=#1^{\circ}$, $k=#2$ \medskip\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#1,scale=#2]
    \draw (0,1) -- (0,0) coordinate (o) -- (1,0) node[midway,name=i] {$1$};
    \node (O) at ($(o)+(-0.5em,-0.5em)$) {$O$};
    \node (I) at ($(i)+(0,-0.5em)$) {$1$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\myDraw{0}{0.5}
\myDraw{45}{0.7}
\myDraw{90}{1}
\myDraw{135}{1.3}
\myDraw{180}{1.5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**another solution**

Here's another solution, I use here the intersection between a line and a node (insensitive to scale) to position the text "O", the text "1" it is positioned at the intersection of the line from "O" and "i".

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\myDraw}[2]{% \myDraw{rotation angle}{scale factor}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
\centering \footnotesize $\theta=#1^{\circ}$, $k=#2$ \medskip\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#1,scale=#2]
    \draw (0,1) -- (0,0) coordinate (o) -- (1,0) coordinate[midway,name=i];
\node[circle,minimum size=2em](circle) at (o){};
\path(o) -- (-2,-2)coordinate(b);
\path (intersection of o--b and circle) coordinate (oo)node{O};
\path (oo) -| (i) node[pos=0.5]{1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\myDraw{0}{0.5}
\myDraw{45}{0.7}
\myDraw{90}{1}
\myDraw{135}{1.3}
\myDraw{180}{1.5}
\end{document}
```

there is a problem with 180 °![image]

Comment: Your solution is working well for rotation, there is only an issue with scaling. I read it too fast and at first I thought you were manually adapting the label position for each case... In conclusion, I've been looking for a solution for the last few days that you had already given to me (at least for the `coordinate` keyword).

Comment: Since I've edited my question many times in the meantime, I've edited your answer to reflect the current MWE... Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

I've eventually came up with a solution to my problem:

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myDraw}[2]{% \myDraw{rotation angle}{scale factor}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
\centering \footnotesize $\theta=#1^{\circ}$, $k=#2$ \medskip\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#1,scale=#2]
    \draw (0,1) -- (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (1,0) coordinate[midway] (I);
    \begin{scope}[scale=1/#2]
      \draw (O) ++ (-0.25,-0.25) node {$O$};
      \draw (I) ++ (0,-0.25) node {$1$};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\myDraw{0}{0.5}
\myDraw{45}{0.7}
\myDraw{90}{1}
\myDraw{135}{1.3}
\myDraw{180}{1.5}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Among the things I've learned, I can name a point inside a path using `coordinate` like this:

```
\draw (0,1) -- (0,0) coordinate (O);
```

I can also name a node with the keyword `name=` so I still can use some convenient options like `midway` or `pos=`:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[midway,name=I] {};
```

But thanks to a comment of Qrrbrbirlbel below, I know now that I can simply use the previous options with `coordinate`:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) coordinate[midway] (I);
```

Once I've done that, I need to manually position my labels and apply the inverse scale factor:

```
\begin{scope}[scale=1/#2]
  \draw (O) ++ (-0.25,-0.25) node {$O$};
  \draw (I) ++ (0,-0.25) node {$1$};
\end{scope}
```

So two issues remain:

- The scale factor must be passed as an argument to my macro.
- I need to manually position my labels which means that I can't use convenient anchors like `below left`).

Comment: You can still do `node[midway] (I) {}` to name the node, but why did use you a node here? A `coordinate` as in the other case would be better: `coordinate[midway] (I)`. By the way, if you insert the coordinate right after the `--` the `midway` setting is used automatically (it’s the default setting).

Comment: I've been reading and reading again the PGF/TikZ documentation but I've never seen such possibilities. Thank you for the tip, I'll edit my answer!

Comment: Take a look at section 16.9 “Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Implicitly” in the [2.10 version of the PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (pp. 193ff.).