# How to rotate a composition of Tikz nodes correctly, without rotating the text of their labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I have seen [How to allow labels' anchors in TikZ to be affected by rotations without rotating the text itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128565/how-to-allow-labels-anchors-in-tikz-to-be-affected-by-rotations-without-rotatin); but that question doesn't seem to answer my problem, so here it goes.

With the MWE below, I get this as the node diagram that I want:

[image: test51.png]

If I uncomment `rotate=180` and `anchor=center`, I get this below - it is good the text in labels is not rotated, as I want it, but the composition is otherwise a mess:

[image: test52.png]

Finally, if I also enable/uncomment the `transform shape` - the composition is better for some elements, worse for others, but now also text in labels is rotated, which I don't want:

[image: test53.png]

So the question is - is there a way to rotate the whole composition correctly, AND not have the text in nodes rotated? My desired output, faked in GIMP:

[image: test54-gimp.png]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47709/2595
\tikzset{
  fitting node/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,
    reset transform,
    fit={(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  },
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset},
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{drc} = [draw, rectangle, line width=1pt, align=center]
\tikzstyle{arr_edge} = [>=latex,->, line width=1pt]

\node[] (tdrag3) at (27.5,1.5) {};
\begin{scope}[shift={(tdrag3)},
%rotate=180,
%anchor=center,
%transform shape,
]
\node[drc,anchor=south west] (nd01) at (0,0) {Some \\ Words};

\node[drc,anchor=south] (nd02) at (3.5,2) {Some Terms};
\node[drc] (nd03) [above=0pt of nd02] {Something};
\node[drc] (nd04) [above=0pt of nd03] {Some Notions \\ Emulation \\ (Next)};

\draw[drc] (5.5,1.5) rectangle (12,5.5) node[fitting node] (nd05) {};
\node[drc,anchor=south,minimum width=6cm,minimum height=0.8cm] (nd06) [above=5pt of nd05.south] {Generic Definition Terms};
\node[drc] (nd07) [above=5pt of nd06.north east,anchor=south east] {Tests \\ (Conversion, Exchange, etc.)};

\draw[drc] let \p1=(nd06.north west), \p2=(nd07.south west), \p3=($(nd07.north west)+(-5pt,5pt)$), \p4=($(nd07.north east)+(0,5pt)$) in (\x1,\y2) -| (\x3,\y3) to node[above left=2pt and -2em]{Plain access} (\x4,\y4) -- ++(0,0.8cm) -| (\x1,\y2);
\node[align=center] (nd05titl) [below=2pt of nd05.north,anchor=north] {Generic Definition};

\draw[drc] (-0.5,6) rectangle (7.5,9) node[fitting node] (nd08) {};
\node[drc] (nd09) [above right=0pt of nd08.south east, anchor=south east] {Generic List Terms\\Word\ Number\ Variable\ Constant} ;
\draw let \p1=(nd01.center), \p2=(nd09.north) in node[drc] (nd10) at (\x1,\y2) [below=0pt,anchor=north] {Some Terms};
\node[drc] (nd11) [above=0pt of nd10.north,anchor=south] {More Than\\Interesting};
\node[drc] (nd12) [above=0pt of nd09.north,anchor=south] {Generic\\List One};
\node[align=center] (nd13) [below=2pt of nd08.north,anchor=north] {Another List};

\draw[arr_edge] (nd01) -- (nd10);
\draw[arr_edge] (nd11) -- (nd12);
\draw[arr_edge] (nd09) -| (nd05);
% wrap in calc $$ for tikzedt
\draw[arr_edge] (nd04) |- ($(nd05.north west)-(10pt,10pt)$) -- ($(nd05.south west)-(10pt,7.5pt)$) -| ($(nd06.south west)+(10pt,0)$);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is tough because your nodes are defined in different manners and with different anchors. One thing that works is replace each `{Node label}` with `{\rotatebox{180}{Node label}}` and then rotate the whole document. However, since some labels span more than one line, you would then have to reverse the order of those lines, and apply `\rotatebox` to each line. It's such a case-specific solution I don't think it's a solution at all, but I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment, @JānisL - I was hoping there was a way to "interrupt" the pgf transformations just for the text (or alternatively, reapply transformations only to text), but I wasn't aware of those complications - good to have them in mind. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a fix - for a halfway fix, using the `add reference` and `fitting nodeR` styles (as per [Connecting line calculations with fitting node in 3D tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167825/connecting-line-calculations-with-fitting-node-in-3d-tikz/167875#167875)), seems to fix the layout of nodes with `rotate` and `transform shape` - <s>I'd just need help now on having the text not rotated in that case</s> (see below); here is the image:

[image: test55.png]

Then, thanks to [#168052 Referencing the contents of lasttikznode, and overlaying them on a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168041/referencing-the-contents-of-lasttikznode-and-overlaying-them-on-a-node/168052#168052), I've found that it is possible to implement a node style, where the `turn` environment from the `rotating` package can be used to rotate the node content box only, implemented as a separate style `rotnt`; then the `drc` node style can simply inherit it - and the only inline change in the nodes' code, would be to style unstyled nodes with `rotnt`, so they also get rotated. And finally, I obtain the desired image:

[image: test56.png]

... and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating} %tlmgr install rotating
\newbox\lastnodebox

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168052/2595
\tikzstyle{rotnt} = [
execute at begin node=\begin{turn}{180}\global\setbox\lastnodebox\hbox\bgroup,
execute at end node=\egroup\copy\lastnodebox\end{turn},
]
\tikzstyle{drc} = [draw, rectangle, line width=1pt, align=center, rotnt]
\tikzstyle{arr_edge} = [>=latex,->, line width=1pt]
%
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47797/2595
\tikzset{add reference/.style={insert path={%
  coordinate [pos=0,xshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth] (#1 south west)
  coordinate [pos=1,xshift=0.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]   (#1 north east)
  coordinate [pos=.5] (#1 center)
  (#1 south west |- #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 north west)
  (#1 center     |- #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 north)
  (#1 center     |- #1 south west)     coordinate (#1 south)
  (#1 south west -| #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 south east)
  (#1 center     -| #1 south west)     coordinate (#1 west)
  (#1 center     -| #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 east)
}}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167825/connecting-line-calculations-
% now fitting node must orient to rectangle coordinate for 3D:
\tikzset{
  fitting nodeR/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,%red, % for debug
    fit={(#1 south west) (#1 north east)},
  },
}
%
\node[] (tdrag3) at (27.5,1.5) {};
\begin{scope}[shift={(tdrag3)},
rotate=180,
anchor=center,
transform shape,
]
\node[drc,anchor=south west] (nd01) at (0,0) {Some \\ Words};

\node[drc,anchor=south] (nd02) at (3.5,2) {Some Terms};
\node[drc] (nd03) [above=0pt of nd02] {Something};
\node[drc] (nd04) [above=0pt of nd03] {Some Notions \\ Emulation \\ (Next)};

\draw[drc] (5.5,1.5) rectangle (12,5.5) [add reference=R1] node[fitting nodeR=R1] (nd05) {};
\node[drc,anchor=south,minimum width=6cm,minimum height=0.8cm] (nd06) [above=5pt of nd05.south] {Generic Definition Terms};
\node[drc] (nd07) [above=5pt of nd06.north east,anchor=south east] {Tests \\ (Conversion, Exchange, etc.)};

\draw[drc] let \p1=(nd06.north west), \p2=(nd07.south west), \p3=($(nd07.north west)+(-5pt,5pt)$), \p4=($(nd07.north east)+(0,5pt)$) in (\x1,\y2) -| (\x3,\y3) to node[above left=2pt and -2em]{Plain access} (\x4,\y4) -- ++(0,0.8cm) -| (\x1,\y2);
\node[align=center,rotnt] (nd05titl) [below=2pt of nd05.north,anchor=north] {Generic Definition};

\draw[drc] (-0.5,6) rectangle (7.5,9) [add reference=R2] node[fitting nodeR=R2] (nd08) {};
\node[drc] (nd09) [above right=0pt of nd08.south east, anchor=south east] {Generic List Terms\\Word\ Number\ Variable\ Constant} ;
\draw let \p1=(nd01.center), \p2=(nd09.north) in node[drc] (nd10) at (\x1,\y2) [below=0pt,anchor=north] {Some Terms};
\node[drc] (nd11) [above=0pt of nd10.north,anchor=south] {More Than\\Interesting};
\node[drc] (nd12) [above=0pt of nd09.north,anchor=south] {Generic\\List One};
\node[align=center,rotnt] (nd13) [below=2pt of nd08.north,anchor=north] {Another List};

\draw[arr_edge] (nd01) -- (nd10);
\draw[arr_edge] (nd11) -- (nd12);
\draw[arr_edge] (nd09) -| (nd05);
% wrap in calc $$ for tikzedt
\draw[arr_edge] (nd04) |- ($(nd05.north west)-(10pt,10pt)$) -- ($(nd05.south west)-(10pt,7.5pt)$) -| ($(nd06.south west)+(10pt,0)$);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```