# Rotate full circuit, without any of the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, transformation

I have a schematics (grossly simplified in the below MWE) that I would like to use both upright and rotated, from the same source (i.e. the only difference should be in the `\begin{tikzpicture}` parameters, *not* in the code of individual nodes).

The problem is that if I use `rotate` without `transform shape`, the whole picture falls apart; and if I use it with `transform shape`, then the labels are rotated as well. I'm looking for a setting that behaves like `transform shape`, but applies a reverse rotation to all text labels.

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167924/2113), I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
\tikzset{
  every label/.append style={reset transform},
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset}
}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\schematics}{
  \draw (0,0) node[dipchip, num pins=6](add){\ttfamily ADD};
  \draw (add.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[left]{\ttfamily x0};
  \draw (add.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[left]{\ttfamily y0};
  \draw (add.pin 5) -- ++(1,0) node[right]{\ttfamily z0};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \schematics
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
  \schematics
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90,transform shape]
  \schematics
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, Ti*k*Z `label` and `ciruitikz` labels are different things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not work, sorry.

[image]

I tried to correct this last year, but changes where too invasives and... scary: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/257

What you can do is rotate `\myangle` with `transform shape`, and counter-rotate the labels manually with a `\rotatebox{\myangle}{...}` command where needed:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myangle}{0}\newcommand\slap[1]{\rotatebox{\myangle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\schematics}{
    \draw (0,0) node[dipchip, num pins=6](add){\slap{\ttfamily ADD}};
    \draw (add.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[left]{\slap{\ttfamily x0}};
    \draw (add.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[left]{\slap{\ttfamily y0}};
    \draw (add.pin 5) -- ++(1,0) node[right]{\slap{\ttfamily z0}};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \schematics
\end{tikzpicture}

\renewcommand{\myangle}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-\myangle,transform shape]
  \schematics
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's almost two years ago. :)

Comment: :-O times flies ... And the pandemic doesn't count, no? :-)

Comment: In some way, it accelerated the time.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ mandatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/2459/